# Why is it IEnumerable.Empty<T>() and not IEnumerable<T>.Empty()?

Tags: c#, methods, static, types, generics

If you want to create an empty IEnumerable of type T, you can create it using the static generic method

```
Enumerable.Empty<T>()
```

See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341042.aspx) for more info.

Why did Microsoft go for this option instead of using a static method on the generic type ( as opposed to a generic static method on the non-generic type ) ?

This method could be used like this :

```
Enumerable<T>.Empty()
```

Which would then return an empty `IEnumerable<T>`.

In my opinion, the second option makes more sense since what I want to create is the generic `IEnumerable<T>`, not a non-generic `IEnumerable`.

*Edit: typo*

Comment: It's `Enumerable.Empty<T>` not `IEnumerable.Empty<T>`

Comment: fyi you mean Enumerable.Empty<T> not IEnumerable.Empty<T>, you can't have static on an interface.

Comment: Yea as soon as I posted my question I realized that the reason was because you obviously can't have static methods on an interface.. Also, Enumerable<T> does not exist.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`IEnumerable<T>` is an interface.
Interfaces cannot contain static members.

The static method is actually on the *`Enumerable`* type, which is a non-generic `static` class.
Therefore, there is no `Enumerable<T>` generic class that could contain the method.

[Static members on generic types should be avoided](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182139.aspx).
Extension methods *cannot* be placed in a generic type.
This is why the static `Enumerable` class is not generic.

Comment: Reading the msdn page, I'm not sure I get why Static members on generic types are evil.

Comment: @Gui: They're not evil; they're just confusing.

Comment: Note that static fields on generic types are multi-valued.  (Each generic parameterization gets its own field; this allows you to make fields of type `T`)

Answer (score 4):

There is a static class called `Enumerable` on which this method is defined. There is not a static class called `Enumerable<T>`. This is because `Enumerable` defines extension methods on `IEnumerable<T>` (all such methods have a generic parameter `T`) and extension methods can not live in generic classes. This is why `Empty<T>` is defined as such.

From §10.6.9 of the specification:

> Extension methods can only be declared in non-generic, non-nested static classes.